# Using a variant of the SUMPRODUCT formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, sumproduct

I want to use following type of `SUMPRODUCT` formula in VBA:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2,C1/B1:B2)
```

It works fine in excel, but when using it as a VBA function it gives an #VALUE! result:

```
Function Test(LineA As Range, LineB As Range, ValueC As Double)

Test = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(LineA, ValueC / LineB)

End Function
```

How can I write that formula with its values using vba?

Comment: Show us the worksheet. You are dividing a double with a range

Comment: Yep. Excel can handle that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Evaluate method...

```
Function Test(LineA As Range, LineB As Range, ValueC As Double)

    Test = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(" & LineA.Address(external:=True) & "," & LineB.Address(external:=True) & "/" & ValueC)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in [evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate)

> Converts a Microsoft Excel name to an object or a value.

> Name... Variant .....A formula or the name of the object, using the naming
> convention of Microsoft Excel. The length of the name must be less than or equal to 255 characters.

```
Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2,C1/B1:B2)")
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I saw a video on youtube explaining the evaluate function! This gonna save me a lot of time! :-) On the same note I learned debug.print and how the brackets work in vba! :-)

Comment: And Option Explicit. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Very similar to the above - but just in case it helps anyone, here is what I did with reference to sheet names and variable column lengths

Set a = Sheets("TheSheetName").Range([M10], [M10000].End(xlUp))
Set b = Sheets("TheSheetName").Range([L10], [L10000].End(xlUp))

c = Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(" & a.Address & ",1/" & b.Address & ")")